# How do I import a development_structure.sql file into my test database in a rails rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm using rails 2.3, and I've generated a `development_structure.sql` using

```
rake db:test:clone_structure
```

How do I import this into my test database? Is there a rails 2.3 compatible rake task for it?

I'm using `development_structure.sql` as a reference for the structure of my database (and not migrations) that I add to my repo, so I want an easy way to test different database structures as the database changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
rake db:structure:dump RAILS_ENV=test
```

UPDATE: I don't know what's wrong with me today.  You should use

```
rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=test
```

If I remember correctly, that will use `structure.sql` if you have the schema_format set to sql

Comment: That command generates a `test_structure.sql` file from the test database, which isn't what I want. I want to import my `development_structure.sql` file (generated from my development database) into my test database.

Comment: sorry, there's something wrong with how I woke up today. can you check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
> rake db:test:prepare
Database mydb_test loaded from db/development_structure.sql.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to transform this .sql into fixtures? The database is recreated every time you do a rake test

Comment: I generate my `development_structure.sql` file from another database from another app, so I'd prefer to minimise the steps it takes to update my rails app.